# Minecraft restart bash script won't run init.d/service command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, linux, ubuntu, minecraft-spigot

## What I intend to do

I'm attempting to make a restart script for my Minecraft server so my friends can use the `/restart` command in-game because they don't have SSH access to my server to restart Minecraft.

## My script

Currently my `restart.sh` script contains

```
exec >> zzz.log
exec 2>&1

set -x

sleep 5

exec /etc/init.d/minecraft start
```

## Script break down

The first two lines will redirect standardout and standarderror (as Linux fluent users will already know) into the `zzz.log` file, this is just so I can capture the output to help me figure what's going on.

`set -x` is also another part to help me figure what's going on, this will output each line that is executed into `zzz.log` because the above lines redirect the output to there.

`sleep(5)` as it suggests will make the script pause for 5 seconds, this is just to ensure Minecraft has had enough time to shutdown.

`exec` will make the following command `/etc/init.d/minecraft start` run in a different process. Since I do not know how the script is invoked, I assumed this could be a child process of the Minecraft server and thus if the Minecraft server process dies, the script will too, having it this way should ensure the command is run.

## My issue

Now, if the Minecraft server is offline and I execute `./restart.sh` the server starts up perfectly fine. When in-game if I type `/restart` the Minecraft server shuts down like its supposed to, but never re-launches again. Looking at my `zzz.log` file I can see the problem lays around the `exec /etc/init.d/minecraft start` command, this line is never successfully executed when Minecraft executes the `restart.sh` script. Why is this?

## init script

I obtained the init script from [here](https://github.com/Ahtenus/minecraft-init). This allows me to `start`, `stop`, `restart` the Minecraft server along with various other commands to control the Minecraft server.

Comment: 1. You seem to have a script called "/etc/init.d/minecraft". From where did you install it? 2. I don't understand how your "restart.sh" stops minecraft. Can you explain?

Comment: @PPanther77 I've added the source of the init script to my question. The reason why I only call start is because the Minecraft server shuts down when `/restart` is called within the game. So it seems redundant to me to stop something that doesn't exist (at least theoretically it wouldn't by that point) which is why I have `sleep(5)` to ensure it has finished shutting down by the time the rest of the script is run.

Comment: What is executing `restart.sh`?

Comment: Easy fix: `/etc/inittab` and add your mc process to the `respawn` list.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I can only assume it would be the Minecraft server process, since I add the path of the shell script in it's config file.

Comment: @dly I'm not very fluent in Linux, but if it starts an executable after its process dies, that sounds like the exact thing I want. I'll give it a go later.

Comment: Yes, respawn does exactly that. Stopping the server for maintenance will be a bit more work: You'll have to remove the server from `/etc/inittab` first, since it doesn't care about how a process died.

Comment: @dly Thanks for the information! From that, I was able to create a working solution for my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## How I came to this solution

Thanks to @dly's comment, I now have a solution!`/etc/inittab` doesn't exist on Ubuntu 16.04, but `/etc/systemd` does which means the solution is a bit different than what it would have been initially.

With a quick read around I was able to find some nice information on [systemd unit files](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers). This is probably not the best resource to use since it doesn't tell you if the particular option should be placed under `[Unit]`, `[Service]` or `[Install]`, but nevertheless, it tells you about the key options needed.

## Follow along for users with a similar issue

The following will assume one has completed the install steps for [Ahtenus' init script for Minecraft/Bukkit servers](https://github.com/Ahtenus/minecraft-init) (this also works perfectly fine for my Spigot server).

To start, you'll need to run this `systemctl enable minecraft.service`. Then you'll probably want to edit the unit file that gets created for you, you can do this with `systemctl edit --full minecraft.service`, this will open a text editor (nano in my case, I didn't get to choose). Here you'll be able to edit the parameters. I configured mine like this:

```
# Automatically generated by systemd-sysv-generator

[Unit]
Documentation=man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
SourcePath=/etc/init.d/minecraft
Description=Minecraft server
Before=multi-user.target
Before=multi-user.target
Before=multi-user.target
Before=graphical.target
Before=shutdown.target
After=local-fs.target
After=remote-fs.target
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target
Conflicts=shutdown.target

[Service]
Type=forking
Restart=always
TimeoutSec=1min
RestartSec=5
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
KillMode=process
RemainAfterExit=no
PIDFile=/home/MyUser/minecraft/minecraft-server.pid
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/minecraft start
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/minecraft stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Most of this is auto created for you, but there may be a few options you'll want to change and add, so I'll go through a few of the options.

- `SourcePath` is the absolute path to the init script.
- `Description` fairly self-explanatory.
- `Restart` has several options, I choose always so no matter how the process dies, it will 'always' be restarted.
- `TimeoutSec` is the timeout for a failed start before it tries to start again.
- `RestartSec` is how long it should wait before starting the service again after shutdown.
- `RemainAfterExit` whether the service should be considered as `active` even after it processes has exited.
- `PIDFile` the path to a PID file for the main process, this should only contain the PID and will be removed when the process is shutdown, but will never be written to by `systemd`. The Minecraft init script will create this on startup.
- `ExecStart` the comand to run to start the service
- `ExecStop` the command to run to kill the service

## Testing it works

Now we can test this works, in case the service has already been started, we can create a new process using `systemctl restart minecraft` even if there wasn't a process for this service, it will create a new one. Then we can use `screen` to connect to the the Minecraft console `screen -r minecraft-server`, now we can type a command for the server to stop either `stop` or `restart`, these can also be used in-game in the same way (remember to prepend the `/` when in-game, the console always does this for you). The Minecraft server should now shutdown, and after the `RestartSec` time specified has elapsed, you should be able to verify the the Minecraft service is running again by either reconnecting to the `screen` again or using `systemctl status minecraft` (use `q` to exit this).

## Further reading

I found this page on the Redhat documentation site mildly informative as well. (Link in comments, I don't have enough rep to post 3+ links).

Comment: Redhat documentation link: `https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_Files.html`

Answer (score 0):

In bash [exec replaces the current script](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) with the command argument without forking a new process.  If restart.sh is being run under a process that goes down, I imagine it would take restart.sh with it.

Comment: So `exec` will run it as a child process?

Comment: I'm not sure about other shells but the bash documentation is pretty clear that exec creates no new processes when run like this.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was going by the information `The  exec()  family  of  functions replaces the current process image with a new process image.` supplied by `man exec`.